# How to create a pdf via template using JS angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, pdf, ionic-framework

I am currently working on an IONIC project that utilizes JavaScript and Angular. I have a requirement to generate a PDF report which includes text, images, and graphs. Instead of manually coding all the content, I would like to use a template where I can input the data dynamically using JavaScript.

Could you please suggest any plugins or tools that would enable me to achieve this functionality?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF). It creates a pdf from html elements or javascript.

Comment: Can I create a template file externally, which is the importanted into this plugin?